# SELECT DISTINCT or GROUP BY on field

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, distinct, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table on my DB that record every call made by employees all over the day.

Every record is a call made by branch lines.

If a branch made 50 calls a day we will have 50 records on DB:

```
branch |            date            
-------+----------------------------
 72489 | 2015-12-03 08:03:58
 34002 | 2015-12-03 08:03:59
 78700 | 2015-12-03 08:05:37
 78700 | 2015-12-03 08:05:53
 78700 | 2015-12-03 08:05:57
 78700 | 2015-12-03 08:06:24
```

What I would like to do is take the first call of the day of every branch line.

I tried to use DISTINCT:

```
SELECT DISTINCT branch, date FROM table WHERE date::date='2015-12-03'::date;
```

Supposedly DISTINCT would avoid repetion on branch, but the result was:

```
branch |            date           
-------+----------------------------
 34002 | 2015-12-03 07:58:24
 34002 | 2015-12-03 08:00:40
 59754 | 2015-12-03 08:01:31
 34002 | 2015-12-03 08:01:56
 59754 | 2015-12-03 08:02:09
 57764 | 2015-12-03 08:02:17
 59754 | 2015-12-03 08:02:28
```

I have some repetions on there.

What I like to have on my result is:

```
branch |            date            
-------+----------------------------
 34002 | 2015-12-03 07:58:24
 59754 | 2015-12-03 08:01:31
 59754 | 2015-12-03 08:02:09
```

I tried with GROUP BY:

```
SELECT branch, date FROM table WHERE date::date='2015-12-03'::date GROUP BY branch;
```

But get this error:

**ERROR:  column "table.date" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function.**

Can someone help-me?

PS: Sorry for the english, my bad.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Too many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant when it comes to date/time.)

Comment: well your last query is fine just drop the date from SELECT and add count instead? you know the date right?

Comment: Unrelated, but: `date::date` is a perfect example why `date` is a really bad name for a column....

Comment: Why is `branch = 59754` twice in the expected result? From your description I would have expected that you only want each branch **once** (Btw: distinct applies to **all** columns in the select list, not only the first, that's why you still get the same branch multiple times).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cast using `::date` implies you are using Postgres. In this case getting the "*the first call of the day of every branch line*" is quite easy by using the `distinct on()` operator:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (branch) branch, date 
FROM table 
WHERE date::date = '2015-12-03'::date
ORDER BY branch, date;
```

Another possibility to solve this kind of query is to use a window function:

```
select branch, date
from (
   select branch, date,  
          row_number() over (partition by branch order by date) as rn
   where cast(date as date) = date '2015-12-03'
) t
where rn = 1
order by branch;
```

The `distinct on ()` solution is Postgres specific, the second solution is ANSI SQL (using ANSI a date literal and ANSI casting)

Comment: Dude, thanks, the first solution work perfectly! Sorry because I forget to specify the database.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution:

```
SELECT 
    branch, 
    (   
        select 
            date 
        from 
            table tb 
        where 
            tb.branch = table.branch
    ) as date 
FROM 
    table 
GROUP BY
    branch
WHERE 
    date::date='2015-12-03'::date;
```

Comment: This will fail if there is more than one call per day. You need a `min(date)` in the scalar-subselect

Answer (score 0):

Select a row as long as no other row from the same date is earlier:

```
SELECT branch, date
FROM table t1
WHERE not exists (select 1 from table t2
                  where cast(t1.date as date) = cast(t2.date as date)
                    and t2.date < t1.date)
```

ANSI SQL compliant.